# Module-info.class is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set, kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I am following the tutorial from IntelliJ site [Intelli J tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-your-first-kotlin-app.html#package-as-jar)

And I add the code for genrating the JAR in build gradle

```
tasks.jar {
manifest {
    attributes["Main-Class"] = "MainKt"
}
configurations["compileClasspath"].forEach { file: File ->
    from(zipTree(file.absoluteFile))
}
}
```

When I run the `gradle jar` task I get this error

```
Execution failed for task ':jar'.
> Entry META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:duplicatesStrategy for details.
```

My project location is : desktop/practvce/kotlin/kmp

What is wrong here?

Comment: This is probably a bug in the Kotlin Gradle plugin, please watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47943 for updates.

Comment: It should help to add duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE to the jar task